# How to control which UIAccessibilityElement receives focus after posting screen change notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have an overlay with accessible elements. When it disappears, I post `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` to cause VoiceOver update.

VoiceOver then picks first element of the screen. How can I make it focus on a specific element by default after posting `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you post the notification you can supply additional information which is either an `NSString` object that `VoiceOver` speaks or an accessibility element that `VoiceOver` moves to.

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, focusItem);
```